# Bash / Python error handling?

Tags: bash, python

I am trying to execute very basic [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) code containing error handling as a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script, but while the code seems to run OK in Python, the code generates problems when executed under Bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
x = input('Enter your number:  ')     
try:
    x = float(x)
    print('Your number multiplied by 2 is:  ', x*2) 
except ValueError:
    print('not a valid choice')
    x == 0
```

This is the error report from Bash:

```
Enter your number:  -p Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cycle.py", line 3, in <module>
    x=input('Enter your number:  ')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'p' is not defined
```

As I understand the input error had to be handled by Python first and then it would return 0 exit status to Bash, but apparently this is not the case?

1. Is my code all right?
2. Is there a way to force Python to handle the error first without evoking Bash?
3. Is there any other critical pitfalls when running Python programs (presumably correctly written) as Bash scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write your code in [Python 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3.0) (looking at "print"), but the shebang suggests [Python 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_2.0). Change the shebang to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and run it by:

```
python3 /path/to/script.py
```

and it will run fine :)

**Explanation:**

As hinted in Florian Diesch' comment, `input()` has changed in Python 3:

In Python 2, `input()` tries to use the input as a Python expression (like `eval()`), while in Python 3, `input()` replaces the `raw_input()` from Python 2.

Comment: the above python script works for me superbly.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, but not when called by `python script.py` I get the same error as OP!

Comment: @Avinash Raj: You get this error if you enter `p` instead of a number if you use Python2 but not if you use Python3 because `input` does a different thing.

Comment: @AvinashRaj sure, but try calling it by python, enter "a"...

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm python3 is default python shell in ubuntu?

Comment: @xiaodongjie yes it is, but it should be called with python3

Comment: @AvinashRaj Didn't you notice anything strange in that output? `print(x, y)` in python3 prints `x y` while in python2 prints `(x, y)`.

Comment: I've edited the shebang to use `env`. It's just a best-practice for Python which can have multiple versions on the system. Deferring to `env` means it should pick the right one.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you `raw_input` function than `input`.

```
input([prompt]) -> raw_input([prompt])
```

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.

If the readline module was loaded, then `input()` will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.

Consider using the `raw_input()` function for general input from users.

You can see about it at https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix it, take `input` inside `try` clause. It's better `except` any error. `x=0` I think you mean assignment there. This way it can accept, values like: `2*3`

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
try:
    x=input('Enter your number:  ')
    x=float(x)
    print('Your number multiplied by 2 is:  ', x*2)
except:
    print('not a valid choice')
    x = 0
```